# using MultiStorage to store records in separate files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to store a set of records like these:

```
2342514224232 | some text here whatever
2342514224234| some more text here whatever
```

....
into separate files in the output folder like this:

output / 2342514224232
output / 2342514224234

the value of the idstr should be the file name and the text should be inside the file. Here's my pig code:

```
REGISTER /home/bytebiscuit/pig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;

A = LOAD 'cleantweets.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (idstr:chararray, createdat:chararray, text:chararray,followers:int,friends:int,language:chararray,city:chararray,country:chararray,lat:chararray,lon:chararray); 

B = FOREACH A GENERATE idstr, text, language, country;

C = FILTER B BY (country == 'United States' OR country == 'United Kingdom') AND language == 'en';

texts = FOREACH C GENERATE idstr,text;

STORE texts INTO 'output/query_results_one' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output/query_results_one', '0');
```

Running this pig script gives me the following error:

```
<file pigquery1.pig, line 12, column 0> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage' with arguments '[output/query_results_one, idstr]'
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified your piggybank jar path?

Comment: yes, it's there and it works fine. Worked before! But not with this use case!  I'm not sure how to go about doing this I've now created an extra id field in my records and now the data looks like 1 | 234234234 | some text  and i'm trying to store the texts in separate files using the id field like this: STORE texts INTO 'output/query_results_one' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output/query_results_one', '0');  but it doesn't work

Comment: Still getting the same error?

Comment: I think delimiter option is required because its not TAB in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option:

```
 MultiStorage('output/query_results_one', '0', 'none', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody stumbles across this post like I did, the problem for me was that my pig script looked like:

```
DEFINE MultiStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage();
...
STORE stuff INTO 's3:/...' USING MultiStorage('s3:/...','0','none',',');
```

The DEFINE statement was incorrectly not specifying inputs/outputs. Foregoing the DEFINE statement and directly putting the following fixed my problem.

```
STORE stuff INTO 's3:/...' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('s3:/...','0','none',',');
```